# Do "regelrecht" and "buchstäblich" have the same meaning?

Tags: meaning

Today I came across [this comic about the meaning of "literally"](http://theoatmeal.com/comics/literally). The point of the comic is that "literally" cannot be used to intensify a narration. I was wondering if the same applies to the German translations "regelrecht" and "buchstäblich".

While [Duden](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/buchstaeblich_geradezu_regelrecht) lists them as synonyms, Wiktionary distinguishes between them and gives "ohne übertragene Lesweise" as the meaning for "[buchstäblich](http://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/buchst%C3%A4blich)" (translation "literally") and words like "wirklich, wahrlich, geradezu" for "[regelrecht](http://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/regelrecht)" (translation "downright").

Comment: As an aside, `wirklich` and `wahrlich` are not good synonyms for `regelrecht`. The semantic area covered by `wirklich` is far greater and `wahrlich` is old-fashioned language that no-one uses nowadays except for ironic effect. Better synonyms are `geradezu, nachgerade, richtiggehend`.

Answer (score 7):

First of all, the synonyms listed on DUDEN are just *words with similar meaning*. They are not necessarily interchangeable without changing connotation. Every word—like in English—has its own special meaning.

*[Buchstäblich](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/buchstaeblich_buchstabengenau)* is derived from *Buchstabe (letter)* and is a possible translation for *literally*. Another similar translation is *[wortwörtlich](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/wortwoertlich)*, or *wortgetreu*. All these words mean that something is *exactly as the word (or letter) says*. It essentially means: *closest match to the original meaning*.

*[Regelrecht](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/regelrecht)* is more about *according to the rules* (*Regel = rule* – *recht = right/well*). So in colloquial speech you use *regelrecht* to say, that something is alright. So it tends more to be like *it’s true* (and that’s the second meaning of the word).
So, actually, the use of *regelrecht* is more about to strengthen your statement rather than saying that is is literal.

I wouldn’t list *regelrecht* as a translation for *literally*, but in some cases it could be the appropriate translation, though.

Comment: To say that something is alright and follows the rules, I'd use „regelgerecht“, not „regelrecht“. „Regelrecht“ feels to me, as a native speaker, to be used for modifying an adverb or adjective.

Comment: How useful is using words according to outdated definitions? That may have been the meaning at some point (“meaning” being what people use it for and understand it as), but unless you are targeting the language of that time, using the word in this way just feels odd.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/3053/discussion-between-em1-and-eugene-seidel)

Answer (score 4):

Es gibt eine Schnittmenge der Bedeutungen, d. h., gelegentlich kann man sowohl `buchstäblich` als auch `regelrecht` sagen. Für `buchstäblich` gibt es aber weniger Anwendungsfälle; man muss mit dem Wort strenger sein.

- In der Eiszeit wurden Felsen durch die Kraft des Eises `regelrecht` zermahlen.
- In der Eiszeit wurden Felsen durch die Kraft des Eises `buchstäblich` zermahlen.
- Im Polizeiverhör wurde der Beschuldigte `regelrecht` zermürbt.

Buchstäblich zermürbt hat nicht einmal die spanische Inquisition.

- Beim Sturz von der Anrichte hat es den Truthahn regelrecht zerlegt.
- Der Hausherr hat daraufhin lediglich den Rehrücken regelgerecht zerlegt (i. S. v. kunstgerecht).

Comment: *Nobody* expects the Spanish Inquisition!

Answer (score 2):

I didn't know there is a prescriptivist comic on the net, LOL @ the gayroller.

Anyway, the same prescriptivist critique that the comic levels at misuse of `literally` can of course be leveled at German speakers misusing `buchstäblich` in exactly the same way. (Just now I have the TV on in the background and there came this line: `Errol Flynn legte sich ihr buchstäblich zu Füßen`, when they mean `Errol Flynn courted her ardently.`) Likewise, the (orthodox, approved) semantic area covered by `literally` is pretty much congruent with the area covered by `buchstäblich`.

Of course, hoping to reverse the trend via prescriptivist critiques is about as likely to succeed as King Canute attempting to stop the tide. Their real function is to act as markers for a self-identified elite (a few people also care out of a genuine love for the language [note how I am demarcating a super-elite within an elite here, LOL]). Eventually the unwashed masses win and then anyone clinging to the old ways is a `fag` and `'tarded` (see: [Idiocracy](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Idiocracy)).

Anyway, no, `regelrecht` and `buchstäblich` do not have the same meaning. `Downright` is a good translation  for `regelrecht`. The Answers that claim that `regelrecht` means `according to the rules` are **wrong**, the people who say that confuse `regelrecht` with `regelgerecht`, which does mean that.

Comment: Dann ist der [DUDEN](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/regelrecht) auch falsch ;p und [WIKI](http://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/regelrecht)

Comment: So ist es. Ein Blick auf die Wolken bei Duden genügt. Jedes der häufig gemeinsam mit `regelrecht` verwendeten Substantive und Verben entspricht seiner Bedeutung als Synonym von `richtiggehend, nachgerade, geradezu`, keines einer Bedeutung als Synonym von `regelgerecht`.

Answer (score 1):

**buchstäblich**

"Buchstäblich" is "verbatim". "Buchstäblich" means letter by letter, word by word.

---

**regelrecht**

"Regelrecht" is "according to the rules".

Comment: I'd regard “downright” as a valid translation of (one of the common meanings of) „regelrecht“. „Was der da macht ist regelrecht kriminell!“

Comment: Das ist keine einleuchtende Erklärung, denn die Bedeutung eines Wortes erschließt sich gerade nicht aus der Kombination der Buchstaben. Zu regelrecht: "Der Zoopfleger wurde vom Elephanten regelrecht an die Wand geschmiert, als dieser einen Schritt zurücktrat". Welche Regeln kamen hier zur Anwendung? Die Regeln der Physik?

Answer (score 1):

A research at Linguee.com yielded evidence, at least I think so, that *buchstäblich* can be used to intensify a statement in German.

The third and fourth examples given there stand out as proof … noone was really crushed nor have there been thousands of split votes … at least I doubt it.

However, most of the *buchstäblichs* there are translated as *literally* which, based on your theory, is probably wrong/not adequate.

Same goes for [*regelrecht*](http://www.linguee.com/english-german?query=regelrecht&source=german) … the very first example shows it. Basic research cannot explode (unless it is done improperly).
All the examples feel right to me as a native German. Thus I would say: the answer is no.
Both words are feasible choices to intensify stuff and their connotation goes beyond a mere “in the actual sense of that word”.

Answer (score 1):

## buchstäblich

> […] Wiktionary distinguishes between them and gives *ohne übertragene Lesweise* as the meaning for *buchstäblich* (translation *literally*)

Fits pretty well.

> ohne übertragene Lesweise – not in the figurative sense

Lots of words are often used figuratively, so are idioms. If you add *buchstäblich*, you mean it in the very literal sense.

> Da musste er buchstäblich die Luft anhalten

*Die Luft anhalten* can be meant in a figurative sense, but by adding *buchstäblich* it's definitely the literal sense. It is not uncommon to leave out a clarifying *buchstäblich* to impart an ambiguous sense.

---

## regelrecht

> […] and words like *wirklich, wahrlich, geradezu* for *regelrecht* (translation *downright*).

*Regelrecht* (when not used in the sense of *proper*/*according to norms*) usually introduces some kind of special expression, mostly giving a very **vivid, demonstrative notion** of what actually happened.

> Der Gockel wurde von dem Fahrzeug regelrecht zerlegt.

Instead one might just say or write

> Der Gockel wurde von dem Fahrzeug getötet/überfahren.

However, the first version uses the verb *zerlegen*, giving a very vivid image of what exactly happened to the *Gockel*.