# Warum kann »regelrecht« dasselbe wie »gleichsam« bedeuten?

Tags: meaning, etymology

In einem Kommentar zu einer Antwort auf eine Frage in diesem Forum (nämlich [hier](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/4335/do-regelrecht-and-buchst%C3%A4blich-have-the-same-meaning/4338#4338)) wurde angezweifelt, dass »regelrecht« die Bedeutung »vorschriftsgemäß«, »gemäß den Regeln« bzw. »im Einklang mit den Regeln« habe. Tatsächlich bedeutet aber etwa der Begriff »Regelrechte Lordose« jene Krümmung der Wirbelsäule, die als normal und gesund angesehen wird. In diesem Beispiel wird also die Krümmung den Regeln gerecht, sie ist daher regelrecht.

Folgender Satz wurde als Beispiel dafür genannt, dass »regelrecht« auch eine andere Bedeutung haben kann:

> Der Zoopfleger wurde vom Elephanten *regelrecht* an die Wand geschmiert, als dieser einen Schritt zurücktrat.

Ganz offenbar wird hier »regelrecht« in der Bedeutung von »gewissermaßen«, »gleichsam« oder »quasi« verwendet.

Ich verstehe den Satz so, dass der Zoowärter vom Elefanten an die Wand gedrückt wurde, während der Elefant sich parallel zur Wand bewegte. Der Zoowärter dürfte daher nicht nur Quetschungen, sondern auch Schürfwunden erlitten haben. Möglicherweise hinterließ er auch Blutflecken an der Wand. Ich glaube aber nicht, dass sich danach der ganze Zoowärter als Fleck an der Wand befunden hat.

Ich verstehe den Satz nämlich nicht so, dass vom Zoowärter nach dem Vorfall nur eine Schicht auf der Wand übrig geblieben wäre. Der Zoowärter wurde also nicht tatsächlich an die Wand geschmiert, aber die Tätigkeit des Elefanten wäre geeignet gewesen etwas anderes (z. B. Butter) sehr wohl an die Wand zu schmieren.

Wie ist zu erklären, dass das Wort »regelrecht«, dessen ursprüngliche Bedeutung – wie ich vermute – eben »gemäß den Regeln« bzw. »im Einklang mit den Regeln« ist, auch diese andere Bedeutung hat, die zumindest auf den ersten Blick nichts mit »Regeln gerecht werden« zu tun hat?

Sinngemäß dieselbe Frage wirft das Wort »gewissermaßen« auf.

Comment: Es beantwortet nicht unbeding tdie Frage, aber es gibt ja viele Adjektive mit positiver oder bestätigender Bedeutung, die im übertragenen Sinne auch als Verstärkung verwendet werden können. Im Satz "Er wurde regelrecht an die Wand geschmiert!" könnte statt regelrecht z.B. auch wirklich, echt, wahrhaft, tatsächlich und förmlich stehen.

Comment: Wie ich in der Frage bereits ausgeführt habe, wurde der Zoowärter eben NICHT wirklich, NICHT echt, NICHT wahrhaft und NICHT tatsächlich an die Wand geschmiert. Der Zoowärter befindet sich nach dem Vorfall ja eben NICHT an der Wand, sondern wird vermutlich verletzt am Boden liegen. Daher kann man »regelrecht« in diesem Beispiel eben NICHT durch diese Wörter ersetzen.

Comment: Doch, weil "geschmiert" auch im übertragenen Sinne mit der Bedeutung "geschlagen" verwendet wird (Ich habe ihm eine geschmiert).

Comment: »Jemandem eine schmieren« bedeutet »jemandem eine Ohrfeige geben«, also »jemandem ins Gesicht schlagen«. Das hat der Elefant aber nicht getan. Der Elefant hat den Wärter an die Wand geschmiert.

Comment: Woher weißt du, dass der Elefant den Wärter keine Ohrfeige gegeben hat?

Comment: @jarnbjo: Ich weiß das, weil in dem einzigen Satz, der von diesem Ereignis erzählt, und der als einziger für diese Diskussion interessant ist, steht, dass der Elefant den Wärter »regelrecht an die Wand schmiert«. Da steht nicht, dass der Elefant dem Wärter eine geschmiert hat.

Comment: Ja klar, wenn du mit dem Irrtum drangehst, dass menschliche Sprache einer formalen Logik folgt.

Answer (score 1):

Es bedeutet nicht "gleichsam", "gewissermaßen" oder "quasi". Nach dem [Eintrag im Duden](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/regelrecht) ist die erste Bedeutung "vorschriftsgemäß", "gemäß der Regel", und die zweite Bedeutung (um die es in der Frage geht)

> ausgesprochen, buchstäblich, direkt, echt, förmlich, geradezu, im wahrsten Sinne [des Wortes], praktisch, rein, richtig[gehend], wahrhaft, waschecht; (umgangssprachlich) leibhaftig

*Warum* es zu dieser zweiten Bedeutung kam, kann ich nicht beantworten; [Grimms Wörterbuch](http://woerterbuchnetz.de/cgi-bin/WBNetz/wbgui_py?sigle=DWB&lemid=GR02573) enthält nur die erste Bedeutung, also muss es eine recht neue Entwicklung sein.

Comment: Die Wörter »buchstäblich«, »echt«, »im wahrsten Sinn« und »wahrhaft« würden in dem vorgebrachten Beispiel aussagen, dass der Zoowärter tatsächlich vom Elefanten vollständig an die Wand geschmiert worden wäre. Der Zoowärter wird aber höchstwahrscheinlich nach dem Vorfall verletzt am Boden liegen, also nicht als Schmierfleck an der Wand kleben. Daher stimmen diese Bedeutungen nicht mit der Bedeutung des Wortes im Beispielsatz überein.

Comment: @Hubert Schölnast: Nein, die Wörter bedeuten nicht "vollständig". Wie immer bei Synomymen, versucht man das Bedeutungsfeld zu umschreiben. Es ist eine intensivierende Beschreibung des Vorgangs (hier: "an die Wand schmieren"). Natürlich wird der Wärter nicht wirklich an die Wand geschmiert und dabei in einen flachen Brei zerlegt, es ist eine farbige Metapher, und "regelrecht" (also "geradezu") unterstützt diese. Und wenn du mit der Erklärung des Dudens unzufrieden ist, wende deine Beschwerden bitte an die Duden-Redaktion, nicht an mich. :-)

Answer (score 1):

#### regelrecht - der Regel entsprechend, richtig

Es gibt eine ganze Reihe gleichfalls umgangssprachlich verstärkend eingesetzter Wörter mit einer ganz ähnlichen Grundbedeutung:

> Sie findet dich **richtig** lieb.
> Er ist **ordentlich** erkältet.
> Das ist **echt** fies von dir!
> Wir sind **tatsächlich** pünktlich gekommen.

Allen und auch dem vielleicht etwas vornehmer klingenden "regelrecht" gemein ist, dass sie einer Aussage eine zusätzliche Wahrhaftigkeit (der Ordnung, den Regeln entsprechende) verleihen sollen. "Regelrecht" ist dabei ein **recht** (*sic*) neues Wort, das erst mit Ende des 19. Jahrhunderts an Bedeutung gewann, zunächst wohl in der ursprünglichen Bedeutung *"einer Regel folgend"* benutzt wurde, was heute zunehmend auch durch *regelhaft* ersetzt wird.

Interessant ist in diesem Zusammenhang, dass **[recht](http://woerterbuchnetz.de/DWB/?sigle=DWB&mode=Vernetzung&lemid=GR02054#XGR02054)** (und nebenbei auch **richtig**) schon im Mittelhochdeutschen auch als verstärkendes Adjektiv gebraucht wird:

> iuch hât **rehte** gotes haʒ dâ her gesendet beide zallem iwerme leide.
> *<sup>Iwein 1203</sup>*

Comment: Ich würde dem zustimmen, wenn der Zoowärter tatsächlich und wahrhaftig an die Wand geschmiert worden wäre. Die von dir genannten Beispiele drücken alle aus, dass etwas tatsächlich genau so ist wie es da steht. Die fett hervorgehobenen Worte sind Verstärkungen. Genau das ist aber im Beispiel aus meiner Frage nicht der Fall. Der Zoowärter klebt nach dem Vorfall eben NICHT an der Wand. Er wurde eben NICHT an die Wand geschmiert. Er liegt höchstwahrscheinlich verletzt am Boden.

Comment: Nun ja, wenn ich mir so einen Zoowärter neben einem Elephanten vorstelle... und wenn da noch eine Wand im Spiel ist: das geht nicht unblutig. Man müsste ein wenig mehr Kontext wissen. So wie ich *regelrecht* kenne, ist es verstärkend.

Comment: Klar, dass das eine blutige Sache ist. Aber einen Blutfleck an der Wand zu hinterlassen und einen Menschen tatsächlich an die Wand schmieren sind doch zwei recht (!) unterschiedliche Dinge.

Comment: Man könnte sich *regelrecht* darüber streiten (wenn  eine umgangssprachliche Verwendung nicht sowieso ohne genaue Regeln erfolgen würde) ;)

Answer (score 1):

Nur mal kurz meine Gedanken dazu:

Wenn ich dich richtig verstehe, das, was dich an den Kommentaren und Antworten stört, ist, dass der Zoowärter danach nicht mehr an der Wand klebt und somit ja nicht an die Wand geschmiert wurde.
Nun gut, der Vergleich hinkt vielleicht ein wenig, aber wenn du Kreide an die Wand schmierst, bleibt ja auch nicht gleich die ganze Kreide an der Wand. Oder du musst halt lange schmieren.

Anyway, ich verstehe den Satz sowieso, dass in dem Moment, wo der Elefant einen Schritt zurücktritt, er den Pfleger an die Wand *drückt*. Und ich glaube, ein Elefant schwankt auch ein wenig in der Bewegung, wodurch quasi eine Bewegung in Richtung Wand als auch parallel zur Wand durchgeführt wird. Eine Wischbewegung. Ungefähr, wie du die Kreide an die Wand drückst, während du die Wand beschmierst.

Beides hinterlässt Spuren, aber sowohl die Kreide als auch der Zoowärter sind noch heil. Wobei das natürlich strikt genommen noch darauf ankommt, wie feste und ausdauernd denn nun geschmiert wird. Auf jeden Fall ist nicht notwendig, dass der Zoowärter anschließend wortwörtlich an die Wand geschmiert wurde.

Insofern ist *regelrecht* tatsächlich nur ein Intensifier. Der Zoowärter wurde also *regelrecht/im wahrsten Sinne des Wortes/geradezu* an die Wand geschmiert.

Über die Herkunft bzw. über die Bedeutungsänderung des Wortes kann ich nichts sagen. Ich denke, hierzu wäre es nötig, sich intensiv damit zu beschäftigen und die Verwendungen über die Jahre hinweg zu analysieren. Zumindest die gängigen Online-Tools bieten dazu nämlich rein gar nichts.

Comment: Obwohl ich 'geradezu' als gutes Synonym für 'regelrecht' bewerten würde, würde ich keines der beiden Wörter als Verstärker verwenden. M.E drücken beide Wörter etwas ähnliches wie 'gleichsam' aus. Eine Ähnlichkeit im weiteren Sinne des Wortes, sozusagen

Comment: Wenn man **mit** Kreide an der Wand schmiert hast du recht, denn dabei verbraucht man nicht die ganze Kreide. Auch wenn man **mit** einem Stück Butter an der Wand schmiert hat man danach noch ein abgeschliffenes Stück Butter in der Hand. Aber der Elefant schmiert nicht **mit** dem Wärter an der Wand. Er schmiert ihn an die Wand. Wenn ich gesehen habe, dass Karl mit einem Eimer voll Kuchenteig ins Klassenzimmer ging, und mir danach berichtet wird, dass er den Teig an die Wand geschmiert hat, dann glaube ich nicht, dass der Eimer noch fast voll ist. Ich glaube dann eher, dass er leer ist. ...

Comment: ... Ich glaube also, dass er alles an die Wand geschmiert hat. Um dasselbe mit Kreide machen zu können müsste man sie zuvor aufschlämmen um eine streichfähige Paste zu bekommen, die man an die Wand schmieren kann. Das verstehe ich unter »die Kreide an die Wand schmieren«. Man müsste an dem armen Zoowärter schon sehr unschöne Veränderungen vornehmen, wobei der Einsatz eines Fleischwolfs vorteilhaft wäre, um ihn tatsächlich, ...

Comment: ... also **regelrecht** an die Wand schmieren zu können, wenn »regelrecht« tatsächlich zum Ausdruck bringen sollte, das etwas tatsächlich, wirklich und wahrhaftig und im wahren Sinn der Worte genau so geschieht wie es geschrieben ist. Aber genau das ist in dem Elefanten-Beispiel eben nicht der Fall.

Comment: @Vogel612 Ich hab jetzt mal "gleichsam" nachgeschlagen, wo es auch OP schon verwendet hatte. Ich kenne das Wort übrigens nicht, die von Wiktionary vorgeschlagenen Synonyme "gewissermaßen" und "sozusagen" unterscheiden sich in diesem Kontext aber meiner Ansicht nach nicht von "regelrecht" oder "geradezu".

Comment: @HubertSchölnast Ich glaube es ist ersichtlich, dass das ganze unterschiedlich aufgefasst wird / werden kann. Ich sehe hier überhaupt kein Problem mit dieser Verwendung, für dich drückt es anscheinend etwas anderes aus. Manchmal darf man Wörter auch einfach nicht auf die Goldwaage legen, denke ich.