# Difference between “buchstäblich” and “wortwörtlich”

Tags: difference, word-choice

I am reading a book in which the author uses both the word *buchstäblich* and the word *wortwörtlich* alternatively. Looking them up, both mean *literally*.
Is there any significant difference in their meaning? By common sense, I would say the former means “according to the letter”, whereas the latter means “according to the word”. But are they used as such?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a difference in usage.

*[Buchstäblich](http://www.dwds.de/?qu=buchst%C3%A4blich)* (literally) is exclusively used in a figurative meaning.

> Er wurde buchstäblich in Stücke gerissen.

*[Wortwörtlich](http://www.dwds.de/?view=1&qu=wortw%C3%B6rtlich)* (verbatim) is used to put emphasis on the precision of the wording.

> Seine Aussage wurde wortwörtlich wiedergegeben.

Comment: No. It might be wrong to use them both for the same, but I do, and I have heard other people do so, too. *Er wurde wortwörtlich in Stücke gerissen.*

Comment: @Jan Yes, it is wrong, although it might be a common mistake. But we should make clear here what the proper usage of these two words would be.

Comment: @Jan: but we can agree that *Seine Aussage wurde buchstäblich wiedergegeben* definitely is wrong, can't we? To my ears using *wortwörtlich* figuratively is not good style either.

Comment: @Takkat Thinking it through, not really. I could even imagine somebody wanting to portray a different meaning through the uses of *buchstäblich* versus *wortwörtlich* in your example … *Stoibers Antworten werden hier buchstäblich wiedergegeben* — you can guess which two letters will be most common ;)

Comment: @Jan: quotes with links to reliable sources or it did not happen.

Answer (score 1):

There's no difference in respect to their common meaning. I addressed that in [another answer of mine](https://german.stackexchange.com/a/4336/1224) to a similar question (*buchstäblich* versus *regelrecht*):

> *[Buchstäblich](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/buchstaeblich_buchstabengenau)* is derived from *Buchstabe (letter)* and is a possible translation for *literally*. Another similar translation is *[wortwörtlich](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/wortwoertlich)*, or *wortgetreu*. All these words mean that something is *exactly as the word (or letter) says*. It essentially means: *closest match to the original meaning*.

So, both words mean the same thing. *Buchstäblich* just refers to the letters of a word, *wortwörtlich* to the word as a whole. Just like you already figured.

That said, there's a second meaning for *wortwörtlich*, as Takkat correctly points out in his answer. If you use the actual words of something said—a quote that is—then this is called *wortwörtlich* (translation: *word-for-word*).

The latter one is addressed by Duden with 1a (the given example is: "eine wortwörtliche Übereinstimmung beider Texte"), while the overlap with *buchstäblich* is addressed with 1b (example is: "er hat sie wortwörtlich aufs Kreuz gelegt")

Comment: What about the figurative usage of *buchstäblich*?

Comment: @Takkat There's only a figurative usage of "buchstäblich", so what is your question?

Comment: While it is true that both Duden and Wiktionary list the two as synonyms, this should (IMHO) be treated as a (maybe common) error. As wen can see from [Grimm](http://woerterbuchnetz.de/DWB/?sigle=DWB&mode=Vernetzung&lemid=GW27461#XGW27461), at least in its origin *wortwörtlich* didn't have the figurative meaning of "buchstäblich". In fact, it was avtively used to underline the verbatim use, as we see from the last example given there: "wenn er (Eulenspiegel) ... als schneidergesell die ärmel wortwörtlich an den rock werfen wollte".

Comment: @Matthias I'm afraid I can't see your point there. In this very example of Eulenspiegel, it *is* interchangeable with "buchstäblich", or in other words: it is the figurative meaning.

Comment: @Em1 [Here's the story](http://www.hekaya.de/sagen/wie-eulenspiegel-sich-bei-einem-schneider-verdingte-und-unter-einer-buette-naehte--eulenspiegel_46.html) that the quote refers to. Eulenspiegel took a command verbatim instead of figuratively. That's what the quote wants to point out, and this wouldn't work by using *buchstäblich* instead of *wortwörtlich*. --- As to your edit: IMHO Duden is outright wrong with 1b), or they intentionally "legalized" a common mistake, as they sometimes do.

Comment: @Matthias Why is it a common mistake? For me, it's absolutely correct. I do use this word in that way and I feel offended if you'd say that this is a mistake. When I wrote my answer, I didn't look up the word in Duden to find out its meaning. I wrote my answer as I know and use the words and then added the links to Duden for the mere sake of reference. (Though I missed the second meaning in the first place. This wouldn't have happened if I had read the Duden entries)