# Gibt es im Deutschen Adjektive, die Januswörter sind?

Tags: adjective, word-classes, antonym

Als [Januswort](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Januswort) bezeichnet man laut Wikipedia

> ein Wort mit mindestens zwei Bedeutungen, wobei eine Bedeutung das Gegenteil einer anderen ist („Auto-Antonymie“).

Mir ist aufgefallen, dass der Wikipedia-Artikel nur ein Adjektiv ("frugal") als Beispiel anführt, und mir sind selbst auch keine weiteren deutschen Januswörter eingefallen, die Adjektive sind.

- Gibt es tatsächlich keine anderen? [Sollte ich völlig daneben liegen und es doch eine größere Anzahl davon geben: bitte nur ein paar Beispiele nennen und fertig. Ich möchte hier keine "große Liste"-Frage starten.]
- Wenn es keine oder (verglichen mit Verben und Nomen) nur sehr wenige weitere gibt: Ist das Zufall, oder hat das mit bestimmten Eigenschaften der Wortart Adjektiv im Allgemeinen oder besonders im Deutschen zu tun?

Comment: Am Rande einer anderen Frage tauchte neulich das Beispiel _schier_ auf (_schier unmöglich_ = _fast unmöglich_, wurde aber von vielen als _völlig unmöglich_ verstanden). Kann aber in dieser Bedeutung nur adverbial benutzt werden.

Comment: @chirlu und "fast", also "nahezu", ist mMn auch kein echtes Gegenteil von "völlig". Aber trotzdem danke für den Hinweis. Ich werde mal über Janus-Adverben nachdenken ;-)

Comment: Absolut richtig, aber wenn man tatsächlich auf der gegenteiligen Bedeutung beharrt, schnurrt auch die Liste bei Wikipedia schnell zusammen.

Comment: Zwar kein echtes Gegensatzpaar, aber doch recht unterschiedlich sind die beiden Bedeutungen von »witzig«: »klug, geistreich« und »lustig, zum Lachen«.

Comment: @HubertSchölnast Dann eher "komisch" -> "lustig" vs "merkwürdig"

Comment: @Em1 Mach daraus doch eine Antwort. Für mich bislang das beste Fundstück. Jemand, der ein komisches Gefühl im Bauch hat, findet das sicher nicht komisch.

Comment: @Matthias: Sind die beiden Bedeutungen hier nicht nur durch den Kontext gegensätzlich? Ich fand beispielsweise [Funky Forest](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Funky_Forest) sowohl merkwürdig als auch lustig, also zugleich komisch und komisch.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper Ich kenne "Funky Forest" nicht, aber es kann schon sein, dass es Einzelfälle gibt, in denen beide Bedeutungen gleichzeitig zutreffen können. M.E. sind das aber Ausnahmen. Wenn ich über jemanden sage "Das ist ein komischer Typ", bedeutet das entweder, das ich ihn (überspitzt gesagt) für den nächsten Otto Waalkes halte _oder_ mir Sorgen mache, dass er demnächst mit einer Knarre auftaucht und Leute über den Haufen schießt - aber nicht beides. Das mag nicht exakt antonym sein, aber für mich ist es Janus-köpfig genug für eine Antwort hier.

Answer (score 9):

**transparent** könnte die Anforderung erfüllen, und zwar so, wie es im übertragenen Sinn zum Beispiel in Bezug auf das Innenleben von Software oder von Organisationen gebraucht wird. Dabei tauchen die folgenden zwei Bedeutungen auf:

- vollständig mit jedem einzelnen Teilaspekt sichtbar
- überhaupt nicht sichtbar

Wenn beispielsweise davon gesprochen wird, dass [Prozesse in einem Unternehmen **transparenter** gemacht werden, um Missbrauch vorzubeugen](http://www.handelsblatt.com/unternehmen/industrie/zehn-jahre-vw-affaere-die-prozesse-sind-jetzt-transparenter/11972752-2.html), so ist damit gemeint, dass man die Prozesse **besser und vollständiger sehen** kann. Wird hingegen beschrieben, dass [eine technische Umstellung völlig **transparent** abläuft](http://www.plone.de/ueber-plone/plone-4/neue-schnellere-ordner-implementierung), so ist damit gemeint, dass man als Benutzer überhaupt nichts davon mitbekommt, der Vorgang also **vollkommen verborgen** bleibt.

Answer (score 9):

> fertig

1. frisch hergestellt, soeben vollendet
2. abgenutzt, reif für den Müll, am Ende der Lebensdauer

Comment: Dabei bezieht sich "fertig" natürlich immer implizit auf einen vorausgegangenen Prozess (1. die Herstellung, 2. die Benutzung), nicht auf das Objekt selber. "fertig zum Essen" und "fertig mit dem Essen" ist auch erst mal gegensätzlich, weshalb man aus "Bist du fertig? Ich beziehe mich aufs Essen." nicht ohne weitere Kontextinformation schließen kann, ob der/die Gefragte schon gegessen haben soll oder nicht. Das Wort "fertig" selber bedeutet aber jeweils dasselbe, es bezieht sich also implizit nur auf etwas anderes. (Möglicherweise entstehen Januswörter aber auch nur auf diese Weise?)

Answer (score 6):

Das Wort, was mir dabei in den Sinn kommt, ist *komisch*. Die beiden Bedeutungen sind zwar nicht direkt antonym, aber schließen sich zumindest häufig gegenseitig aus.

Komischerweise gilt das übrigens auch für das englische Pendant *funny*. Ob das nun *merkwürdig* oder *lustig* ist, sei dahingestellt.

Comment: 1. Du solltest explizit hinschreiben, welche Bedeutungen von »komisch« du meinst (nämlich »lustig« und »merkwürdig«). 2. Das Gegenteil von »komisch« im Sinn von »lustig« ist »ernst«. Das Gegenteil von »komisch« im Sinn von »merkwürdig« ist »erwartungsgemäß«. Wenn »lustig - merkwürdig« ein Gegensatzpaar wäre, müssten »lustig - erwartungsgemäß« und »ernst - merkwürdig« synonyme Paare sein, oder wenigstens sinnverwandt. Das ist aber nicht mal annähernd der Fall.

Comment: Aus genau diesem Grund habe ich auch meine eigene Eingebung (»witzig«: »klug, geistreich« und »lustig, zum Lachen«) nur als Kommentar, und nicht als Antwort geschrieben, weil dieselbe Kritik, die für »komisch« gilt, auch auf »witzig« zutrifft. Weder »witzig« noch »komisch« erfüllen die in der Frage geforderte Eigenschaft der Auto-Antonymie.

Comment: Die beiden Bedeutungen von »komisch« schließen einander auch keinesfalls aus: Wenn ein Mann anstelle eines Hutes auf dem Kopf eine Gießkanne trägt, ist das sowohl lustig als auch merkwürdig.

Comment: @HubertSchölnast 1) Bedeutungen hinschreiben -> Hab ich doch gemacht. 2) Keine Antonyme -> Hab ich doch auch gesagt. 3) Schließen sich grundsätzlich aus -> Hab ich nicht behauptet. – Danke und einen schönen Tag noch.

Comment: Ad 1: Ich habe deine Antwort nun entsprechend editiert. Ad 2: Wenn in der Frage ausdrücklich nach Worten mit zwei antonymen Bedeutungen gefragt wird, warum schreibst du dann etwas als Antwort, von dem dir klar ist, dass es die gestellte Frage nicht beantwortet?

Comment: @HubertSchölnast Sei bitte nicht päpstlicher als der Papst. Die Frage verlinkt auch auf den Wikipedia-Artikel, in dem einige Beispiele aufgeführt sind, deren jeweilige Bedeutungen zwar keine echten Gegensatzpaare sind, aber einander doch deutlich widersprechen. Insofern ist _komisch_ durchaus im Sinne der Frage, und deshalb habe ich Em1 gebeten, aus seinem Kommentar eine Antwort zu machen.

Comment: @Matthias Ich kann Hubert nur beipflichten. Du fragst nach autoantonymen Adjektiven. In der Wikipedialiste hat bis auf Bundesstaat fast jedes Wort zumindest zwei annähernd gegensätzliche Bedeutungen.

Comment: @Daniel Aus der Wikipedia-Liste sind für mich auch die jeweiligen Bedeutungen von _aufheben_, _ausbauen_ und _verabschieden_ nicht direkt antonym. Und wenn jemand etwas merkwürdig, unklar und irritierend findet, wird er darüber selten zugleich lachen. Um mein obiges Beispiel zu wiederholen: wenn ich nach einer Mahlzeit ein komisches Gefühl im Bauch habe, finde ich das nicht komisch, sondern mache mir Sorgen.

Comment: @Matthias. Über die Auto-Antonymie einiger Worte der Liste mag man vielleicht streiten. Die meisten können jedoch zumindest vom Sinn her antonyme Bedeutungen haben. Ausbauen (erweitern, entfernen) usw. Merkwürdig und lustig sind jedoch nicht antonym. Etwas kann ja durchaus merkwürdig und gleichzeitig lustig sein, wie Hubert auch schon angemerkt hat. Du sagtest in Deinem Kommentar, "die einander doch deutlich widersprechen" bzgl. der Bedeutungen der Worte in dem Wiki-Artikel. Das ist bei komisch und witzig (Bsp. von Hubert) einfach nicht gegeben.

Comment: @Matthias Falls Du den Widerspruch konkret darstellen kannst, bin ich gerne bereit, meine Meinung zu ändern. Dein Beispiel mit der Mahlzeit: Du findest das Gefühl komisch, sonst würdest Du es nicht so nennen. Hier ist die Bedeutung merkwürdig. Dass Du Dir deswegen Sorgen machst, sagt doch nichts über die Bedeutung von komisch aus. Selbst wenn Du etwas lustig fändest, könntest Du Dir deswegen Sorgen machen. Selbst wenn der Bezug gleich wäre, wäre Sorgen machen nicht antonym zu lustig sein.

Answer (score 3):

So etwas kenne ich eigentlich nur bei Negativ-Adjektiven, die auf einmal postive Bedeutung entwickeln können, wie zB irre in "Das ist irre gut". Hierzu könnte man auch "toll" zählen. Es gibt ein paar solche Adjektive, aber ihre Anzahl ist relativ gering.

Den Begriff Januswörter habe ich noch nie gehört, eigentlich kein geläufiger Begriff, aber Wikipedia hat ein Talent, die seltensten Begriffe auszukramen und zu tun, als ob das normale Begriffe wären. Man sollte schon einen Hinweis geben wie "selten gebraucht".

Comment: Hat *irre* in *Das ist irre gut.* denn die gegenteilige Bedeutung zu der die *irre* sonst hat? Die Bedeutung von *irre* an sich wandelt sich nicht ins Gegenteil sondern verstärkt einfach nur das *gut*.

Comment: "Irre" heißt verrückt, nicht normal im Kopf und ist ein negativer Begriff. In "Das ist irre"  ist es aber positiv gemeint ( entwickelt über Das ist irre gut).

Comment: Nochmals die Frage nach dem Gegenteil: Steht *irre* in diesem Fall dann für "normal im Kopf, nicht verrückt"? Es geht ja nicht um eine positive oder negative Konnotation. Zum Beispiel: Köstlich ist eher positiv besetzt, teuer eher negativ. Trotzdem sind die beiden nicht gegensätzlich.

Comment: Die semantische Entwicklung ist: Etwas is so gut, das es schon fast verrück ist.

Comment: Das bezweifle ich doch auch gar nicht. Verrückt im Sinne von unglaublich, unnormal etc. Jetzt ist aber immer noch meine Frage offen, inwiefern dies jetzt das Gegenteil zu der ursprünglichen Bedeutung ist. Du sagst quasi "verrückt" sei das Gegenteil von "unglaublich" oder "unnormal"? Ich behaupte gar nicht, dass Dein Beispiel nicht stimmt, ich sage nur, es ist keine Auto-antonymie vorhanden, da die Bedeutungen nicht antonym sind.

Comment: Nur weil du den Begriff nicht kennst, ist er ungebräuchlich?

Comment: Kennst du ihn? Ich vermute in irgendeiner lingistischen Abhandlung hat jemand diesen Begriff kreiert. Leider sagt Wikipedia nicht, wer den Begriff aufgebracht hat. Mein Lexikon H. Bußmann, Lexikon der Sprachwissenschaft,  1990,  hat den Begriff nicht. @Max Ried

Comment: Ich lese gerade den Wikipediaartikel Januswort zum ersten Mal. Aber über Akzeptanz und Verbreitung des Begriffes wird nichts gesagt. Wenn man Januswort googelt, kommt nur der Wikipediaartikel. Für großen Bekanntheitsgrad spricht das nicht gerade.

Comment: Ich kenne ihn nicht, verallgemeinere das aber auch nicht.

Comment: Ich finde es völlig normal, dass ein Lexikon Begriffe beschreibt, aber keine Wertung vornimmt. Was dem einen völlig exotisch erscheint, ist einem anderen ein vertrauter Begriff aus seiner Fachdomäne. "Selten gebraucht" wäre deshalb wertend und subjektiv. [Google Books](https://www.google.de/search?tbm=bks&hl=de&q=januswort) findet immerhin ca. 40 Bücher, die den Begriff verwenden. Beim Drüberfliegen habe ich den Eindruck, dass sie ihn zum Teil noch laxer verwenden als Wikipedia, nämlich seinem Ursprung entsprechend als "Wort mit 2 Gesichtern". Z.B. wird "gut" mehrfach als Januswort bezeichnet.

Comment: @Daniel "Das ist ein irrer Artikel" kann zumindest sowohl eine stark positive wie auch stark negative Bewertung darstellen. Ganz unrecht hast Du aber auch nicht - während die negative Bewertung eher auf die rationale Qualität des Gegenstands abzielt, betont die positive Bewertung die beim Subjekt ausgelöste Begeisterung. In diesem Sinne sind die beiden Bedeutungen dann eher orthogonal als entgegengesetzt.

Comment: _Toll_ wäre ein guter Treffer, wenn die beiden Bedeutungen koexistieren würden. Mir scheint, sie haben sich eher abgelöst. _Das ist ein toller Hund_ hatte vor 150 Jahren eine ganz andere Bedeutung als heute. Vom Inhalt her sicher nicht entgegengesetzt, von der damit verbundenen Wertung hingegen schon.

Comment: @Matthias Ad 1. Hier kommt das gleiche zum Tragen. "Irre" verstärkt nur die eine wie die andere Bedeutung. Was man verstärken will, wird nur aus dem Kontext klar oder man weiss es, da man den Artikel kennt. "Irre gut" oder "irre schlecht". In beiden Fällen ist "irre" synonym zu "sehr".

Comment: @Matthias Ad 2. Du schreibst -stark verkürzt- die verbundene Wertung ist entgegengesetzt und daher wäre "toll" ein guter Treffer. Daraus liesse sich folgern, alle Worte, deren Wertung gegensätzlich ist, wären antonym. Im Wiki-Artikel steht *antonym (eine entgegengesetzte Bedeutung habend)*. Provokant gefragt, worüber diskutieren wir denn jetzt?

Comment: @Daniel Ad1: Nicht in beiden Fällen. Im negativen Fall ist es das Synonym zu _wirr_, _verwirrt_, _geistesgestört_.

Comment: @Daniel Ad2: Über Wörter mit 2 Gesichtern. Und ich sage dass jetzt bewusst so schwammig, weil ich mich auf Haarspaltereien hier nicht einlassen will.

Answer (score 3):

> Ich kümmere mich **gleich** darum.

Das Wort **gleich** in diesem Satz kann sowohl *unverzüglich/auf der Stelle/sofort* ausdrücken als auch *nicht sofort/zu einem späteren Zeitpunkt*. Die genaue Bedeutung hängt von der Betonung und vom Kontext ab.

Oder man kann die gemeinte Wortbedeutung durch weitere Ergänzungen klarstellen:

> Ich kümmere mich gleich auf der Stelle darum.

oder:

> Ich kümmerer mich erst gleich darum.

Comment: Die Sätze mit den Ergänzungen klingen für mich etwas merkwürdig. In jedem Fall ist auch _gleich_ aber kein richtiges Adjektiv. :-)

Comment: Ich stimme nicht ganz zu. Der Satz ist für mich eindeutig "bald". Das kann zwar sehr unmittelbar sein ("In dem Moment, wo ich 'Der Baum fällt gleich' rief, fiel der Baum auch schon um"), aber die Kernaussage von "gleich" ist mehr "in naher Zukunft". Es kann durchaus mit "sofort" ausgewechselt werden, jedoch bedeutet "sofort" nicht zwingend "genau jetzt": "Ich kümmere mich sofort darum, ich mache das hier nur noch schnell fertig". Hier wäre "sofort" == "gleich", aber eben nicht "jetzt". Verwirrung kommt oft durch die Kombination "jetzt gleich" auf, wobei hier i.d.R. es auch klar sein sollte.

Comment: In beiden Fällen halte ich »gleich« auch für unpassend. »Auf der Stelle« heißt ja so viel wie »jetzt« oder spätestens »sofort«. »Gleich« wäre noch etwas später, und noch später als gleich ist »bald«, wie Em1 schon angemerkt hat.

Answer (score 2):

Ich meine zu beobachten, dass ***wortwörtlich*** eine ähnliche Entwicklung erfährt wie das Englische Gegenstück *literally,* bei dem mittlerweile sogar Wörterbücher angeben (z. B. [dieses](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/literally)), dass es gegenteilige Bedeutungen haben kann, nämlich einmal *im wörtlichen Sinne* und einmal *im übertragenen Sinne.*

Zum Beispiel wird man vermutlich folgende Sätze beobachten können, in denen *wortwörtlich* eine entgegengesetze Bedeutung hat:

> Dieses Zäpfchen musst du dir wortwörtlich in den Hintern schieben.
>
> Diese Idee kannst du dir wortwörtlich in den Hintern schieben.

Comment: Das ist aber auch wieder nur adverbial verwendbar; ein _wortwörtliches Zitat_ mag gerade noch angehen, aber das wäre die ursprüngliche Bedeutung. (*Das hat sie wirklich so gesagt? –  Wortwörtlich!*)

Comment: Siehe dazu auch http://german.stackexchange.com/questions/23164/difference-between-buchst%C3%A4blich-and-wortw%C3%B6rtlich

Answer (score 1):

[Ansonsten](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/ansonsten)

Bedeutungen:

1. im Übrigen, darüber hinaus
2. im anderen Fall, im gegensätzlichen Fall

Comment: Als Januswort würde ich es noch durchgehen lassen, aber es ist doch kein Adjektiv?

Answer (score 0):

Spiegelbild, spiegelbildlich

1. dasselbe
2. das Gegenteil

Beispiel (ich bitte im Voraus um Verzeihung, dass ich dieses allgegenwärtige Thema hier hineinschleppe):

> Die heutige Corona-Situation ist ein Spiegelbild der letztjährigen

kann heissen:

- die Situation ist genau gleich wie letztes Jahr (steil ansteigende Fallzahlen)
- die Situation ist genau umgekehrt zu letztem Jahr (hohe Zahlen in Deutschland, tiefe Zahlen in Frankreich)

Comment: "die Situation ist genau gleich wie letztes Jahr" - für diesen Fall würde ich "Spiegelbild" dann eher als falsche Wortwahl ansehen. Aber in meiner Frage geht es ja um Adjektive, also käme sowieso nur "spiegelbildlich" in Betracht. Und da fällt es mir noch schwerer, dafür eine "ist genau gleich"-Bedeutung zu sehen.

Answer (score -1):

**fix**

1. fest, feststehend, unbeweglich
2. schnell, behende

[DWDS](https://www.dwds.de/wb/fix#1) schreibt zur Etymologie:

> Aus fix ‘beständig’ entwickelt sich ‘sicher, geschickt, gewandt, erfahren’ (17. Jh.) und schließlich auch ‘behende, rasch, schnell’, seit dem 17. Jh. häufig und wohl durch die Studentensprache verbreitet