# List of German auto-antonyms

Tags: big-list

I’m using *auto-antonym* to designate words that have two opposite (or nearly opposite) meanings.

The best example I know of an auto-antonym in German is the verb *anhalten*, which can mean both *to stop* and *to continue*.

Such words can be particularly bewildering to someone learning the language.  It would therefore be useful to round them up, and mark them for special consideration as problematic.

If such a list already exists, a link to it would be greatly appreciated.

If not, let’s make one here.

---

Here are some examples of (near) auto-antonyms in English:

- the verb *sanction* means *approve of*, but the noun *sanction* refers to a form of punishment;
- *oversight* can mean *supervision* (as in *to watch over*), but *an oversight* is *a **failure to see** something*;
- *to cleave* means *to split, divide*, but *to cleave to* means *to adhere to, keep close to*;
- *on reflection* or *upon reflection* describes an action carried out after sustained deliberation, whereas *on reflex* describes exactly the opposite: an act carried out instinctively, and without any conscious thought; (this one is, admittedly, a bit of a stretch, even if *reflection* and *reflex* are two variants of the same original *reflexio*)

Comment: Closely related question in German, asking for adjectives only: http://german.stackexchange.com/questions/24140/gibt-es-im-deutschen-adjektive-die-janusw%C3%B6rter-sind

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not too surprisingly, there is an English Wikipedia article on [Auto-antonym](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Auto-antonym). On the left side it has a link to the corresponding German article, which is at [Januswort](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Januswort). It has a list of 17 such German words and comments that words of this type are somewhat rarer in German than in English.

Comment: Well, all of this is surprising to *me*, quite obviously...  In particular, I never even heard the word "auto-antonym" before.  I used it in this post thinking it was a nonce coinage, in the spirit of "for-lack-of-a-better-word".  But thanks.